# My comparison seems to be wrong

Tags: javascript, if-statement, comparison, conditional-statements

I'm trying to compare to functions. Each function have this: return returnArr.toString();   as a return, which are strings both of them.

```
if ( moveRight() == paintFood(235,10,"blue") ){
alert("Food!")
};
```

But it's not the same like this one:

```
if ("A" == "A"){
alert("Right comparison");
};
```

Why ???

Comment: Show us the code for the two methods.

Comment: Use ".equals()" function.

See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: Not to sound condescending, but a modicum of (consistent) [indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) wouldn't go astray.

Answer (score 0):

```
new String("a") == new String("a")
```

evaluates to false.

Try

```
if ( moveRight().valueOf() == paintFood(235,10,"blue").valueOf() ){
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help.
Problem solved meanwhile. The if condition is put within a function to runs it whether it is needed, which the if condition only was not at the right place:

```
function check (){
if ( moveRight() == paintFood(235,10,"blue") ){
alert("Food!")
};
};
```